# Error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: python

Im new in python and am getting a strange error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

When i execute the following code:

```
  class Workspace(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    """ This class is for managing the whole GUI `Workspace'.
        Currently a Workspace is similar to a MainWindow
    """

    def __init__(self):
        #p= subprocess.Popen(["java -Xmx256m -jar bin/HelloWorld.jar"],cwd=r'/home/karen/sphinx4-1.0beta5-src/sphinx4-1.0beta5/', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize= 4024)
        try:
            from Queue import Queue, Empty
        except ImportError:
            while True:
    #from queue import Queue, Empty  # python 3.x
                print "error"

        ON_POSIX = 'posix' in sys.builtin_module_names

        def enqueue_output(out, queue):
            for line in iter(out.readline, b''):
                queue.put(line)
            out.close()

        p= Popen(["java -Xmx256m -jar bin/HelloWorld.jar"],cwd=r'/home/karen/sphinx4-1.0beta5-src/sphinx4-1.0beta5/',stdout=PIPE, shell=True, bufsize= 4024)
        q = Queue()
        t = threading.Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(p.stdout, q))
        #t = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(p.stdout, q))
        t.daemon = True # thread dies with the program
        t.start()

# ... do other things here
        def myfunc(q):
            while True:

                try: line = q.get_nowait()
         # or q.get(timeout=.1)
                except Empty:
                    print('Vacio')
                else: # got line
    # ... do something with line

                    print line  


        thread = threading.Thread(target=myfunc, args=(q,))
        thread.start()
```

This part of code is reading from a program's stdout.When i execute  `myfunc` out of the thread it works ! But when i execute it in the thread fais... 
Any suggestion?

Comment: What is `q` in the code above?

Comment: a [synchronized queue class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Empty)?

Comment: @JasonSperske: Yes, but the question is _which_ one—if it's `queue.Queue`, it's probably a Python configuration problem, and the best solution is to uninstall and reinstall Python; if it's `foomodule.Queue`, it's likely to be a bug in the `foo` library.

Comment: PS, @karensantana: What Python version, and what platform?

Comment: i have a queue class: q = Queue()

Comment: Python 2.7.3 on linux (fedora 16)

Comment: My previous comment was wrong; I thought `myfunc` was a method of `Workspace`, not a local function within `__init__`. That's correct, if slightly confusing, so it can't be related to your crash. Any chance `myfunc` or `enqueue_output` do anything with the `self` `Workspace`, or do you get the crash even with this stripped-down version? If the latter, does it still crash if you strip it down further to remove all the Qt (just replace the superclasses with `object`, scrap any other classes, and have the main script just do `Workspace()`)?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

`"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"` is the string that Linux prints when a program exits with a `SIGSEGV` signal and you have core creation enabled. This means *some* program has crashed.

If you're actually getting this error from running Python, this means the Python interpreter has crashed. There are only a few reasons this can happen:

1. You're using a third-party extension module written in C, and that extension module has crashed.
2. You're (directly or indirectly) using the built-in module `ctypes`, and calling external code that crashes.
3. There's something wrong with your Python installation.
4. You've discovered a bug in Python that you should report.

The first is by far the most common. If your `q` is an instance of some object from some third-party extension module, you may want to look at the documentation.

Often, when C modules crash, it's because you're doing something which is invalid, or at least uncommon and untested. But whether it's your "fault" in that sense or not - that doesn't matter. The module *should* raise a Python exception that you can debug, instead of crashing. So, you should probably report a bug to whoever wrote the extension. But meanwhile, rather than waiting 6 months for the bug to be fixed and a new version to come out, you need to figure out what you did that triggered the crash, and whether there's some different way to do what you want. Or switch to a different library.

On the other hand, since you're reading and printing out data from somewhere else, it's possible that your Python interpreter just read the line `"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"` and faithfully printed what it read. In that case, some other program upstream presumably crashed. (It's even possible that nobody crashed—if you fetched this page from the web and printed it out, you'd get that same line, right?) In your case, based on your comment, it's probably the Java program that crashed.

If you're not sure which case it is (and don't want to learn how to do process management, core-file inspection, or C-level debugging today), there's an easy way to test: After `print line` add a line saying `print "And I'm OK"`. If you see that after the `Segmentation fault` line, then Python didn't crash, someone else did. If you don't see it, then it's probably Python that's crashed.

Comment: Im reading from a program's stdout written in java... it means that this code has crashed?

Comment: No. It's most likely your Queue module that crashed from what I gathered.

Comment: Hold on… Did your Python executable crash with a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`, or did it just print the line `"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"`? If it's the latter case, then yes, it means your Java program crashed. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: @abarnert What is your recommendation? Do i have to install python again?, a new version of python? Another library?

Comment: If your `Queue` comes from the built-in `Queue` module, and calling `q.get_nowait()` on it crashes, then yes, I'd recommend uninstalling and reinstalling Python, because that should never happen. If your `Queue` class comes from some other module… well, it depends what module it comes from, and where you got it.

Comment: @karensantana: I added a comment to the original question which may be relevant.

Comment: In my case, it was an incorrectly installed python version which happened after the upgrade.

Comment: Python 3 now comes with a helpful utility that goes a little way in helping you trace where the issue might be https://docs.python.org/3/library/faulthandler.html

Comment: So a faulty RAM could not be the reason?

Comment: For those wondering how to use `faulthanlder`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731115/how-to-debug-a-python-segmentation-fault

Answer (score 82):

There is one more reason for such failure which I came to know when mine failed

- You might be working with a lot of data and your RAM is full

This might not apply in this case but it also throws the same error and since this question comes up on top for this error, I have added this answer here.

Comment: Thanks. I was running 8 thread and wondering why I am getting this error.

Comment: Valid point, running 8 threads and generating 4000 data entries per second in a python dict did this to my program.

Comment: are there good solutions to reduce RAM?

Answer (score 24):

It's worth trying faulthandler to identify the line or the library that is causing the issue as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58825725/2160809 and in the comments by Karuhanga

```
import faulthandler


faulthandler.enable()
// bad code goes here
```

or

```
$ python3 -q -X faulthandler
>>> /// bad cod goes here
```

Comment: Indeed. Actually, I'm impress of why the elected answer didn't include this. Thanks bro :). You saved a life today.

Comment: glad this helped :)

Comment: Have a look, CookieMonster: https://doadm-notes.blogspot.com/2020/08/segmentation-fault-in-python.html

Comment: oh that's nice :)

Answer (score 5):

In my case: I forgot to **activate virtualenv**

I installed "pip install example" in the wrong virtualenv

Comment: Incase anyone else made the same mistake, here is how to activate it...
_Activate the virtual environment_
You can activate the python environment by running the following command:
Mac OS / Linux
`source <virtualenv>/bin/activate`
Windows
`<virtualenv>\Scripts\activate`
link: https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/26/python-virtual-env/

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was importing load_workbook from openpyxl before importing mysql.connector. I just switch the order and it started working again.

**Segmentation fault (core dumped) error**

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import mysql.connector
```

**Solution**

```
import mysql.connector
from openpyxl import load_workbook
```

Answer (score 2):

Mildly unrelated to the question, but since this page appears whenever you search *"(core dumped) python"* then I might share a common problem that causes this error.

```
OpenCV cv2.imshow() sometimes raises this error on servers without graphical interfaces.
```

Hope I helped. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I imported pyxlsd module before module wich works with db Mysql. 
After I did put Mysql module first(upper in code) it became to work like a clock.
Think there was some namespace issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while using Python and Pytorch. The problem in my case was old checkpoints. Due to old checkpoints, Pytorch was not able to load or create new graphs. After deleting old checkpoints, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the memory swap on my machine fixed this issue.

https://linuxhint.com/increase-swap-space-linux/