# Cant install Bitnami Django Stack on CentOS 7

Tags: django, centos7, bitnami

I cant install Bitnami Django Stack on CentOS 7.

I keep getting an error that says;
" Segmentation fault (core dumped) "

I am able to easily install the same downloaded package on ubuntu server but NOT on CentOS 7.
kindly help thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654449/error-segmentation-fault-core-dumped Try this, in Similar situation this post helped me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not been able to reproduce the issue running the installer on a centos 7 VM with 1025 MB of memory. Are any other memory heavy processes running? Which exact Django Stack version are you using?

Comment: Yes i had other memory heavy processes running. Thanks for helping me to solve this issue.